# How to HTML encode en dash in vb.net?

Tags: html, .net, vb.net, decode, encode

My string :

> Feste begründen die Identität einer Gemeinschaft und ihr
>   Selbstverständnis nach innen. Eng damit verbunden sind Emotionen, die
>   zunächst im Zusammenhang mit einer gefühlten Zugehörigkeit zu einer
>   Fest-Gemeinschaft zu verstehen sind. Mit jedem Fest verbindet sich
>   aber auch eine emotionale Überschreitung des Alltags: Der bestimmende
>   festliche Eindruck – die feierliche Gestimmtheit – ist der einer
>   erhöhten Bedeutungshaftigkeit des Lebens, durch die sich das Festliche
>   aus dem Lauf des Alltagslebens hervorhebt und dessen Wirkmächtigkeit
>   zuvörderst anhand der Analyse des bürgerlichen Geburtstages sinnfällig
>   demonstriert werden soll.

I want to encode as HTML the above string

I tried:

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(strings)
```

I am getting output as :

> Feste begr&#252;nden die Identit&#228;t einer Gemeinschaft und ihr
>   Selbstverst&#228;ndnis nach innen. Eng damit verbunden sind Emotionen,
>   die zun&#228;chst im Zusammenhang mit einer gef&#252;hlten
>   Zugeh&#246;rigkeit zu einer Fest-Gemeinschaft zu verstehen sind. Mit
>   jedem Fest verbindet sich aber auch eine emotionale
>   &#220;berschreitung des Alltags: Der bestimmende festliche Eindruck –
>   die feierliche Gestimmtheit – ist der einer erh&#246;hten
>   Bedeutungshaftigkeit des Lebens, durch die sich das Festliche aus dem
>   Lauf des Alltagslebens hervorhebt und dessen Wirkm&#228;chtigkeit
>   zuv&#246;rderst anhand der Analyse des b&#252;rgerlichen Geburtstages
>   sinnf&#228;llig demonstriert werden soll.

You can see the above output that the en-dash is not encoded, kindly suggest any solution for this.

Also I want to encode 100% without missing any characters like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "I want to encode 100 % without missing any characters like this."

No need to do this if you are using the correct format. In fact, you also don't need to encode en dash or any other non-ascii characters. But if for some reason you really ought to use this feature, you can write:

```
Dim enDash = "&#8211;"
myString.Replace(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(enDash), enDash)
```